# Start a session in read-only mode

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

My problem is the following:

I have a page which runs a series of AJAX calls e.g.

```
$.ajax({ url: "/user/post1" });
$.ajax({ url: "/user/post2" });
$.ajax({ url: "/user/post3" });
...
$.ajax({ url: "/user/postN" });
```

(I've determined the ids beforehand)

I've also got:

```
$.ajax({ url: "/user/modifysessiondata" });
```

Now the problem is that I need to start the session in each and every request (to get the current user) and in addition "/user/modifysessiondata" also needs to modify session data.

However I've noticed that if I just execute all AJAX requests at once it's possible that if a `/user/postX` request starts before `/user/modifysessiondata` request and ends after that then it will save the session data as it was when the request was called and therefore will overwrite the session data that was set by the 2nd call.

My question is:

Is it possible to flag the session started in a specific request as "Read only"? Would I need to create a new custom `StartSession` middleware for this?

Am I just doing something completely ridiculous?

Note: To clarify I'm talking about the Laravel session. I am using a redis backed session storage.

Comment: Are you sure you are not modifying the variables yourself? Each request should block the session so I don't see how one request could keep it open while another modifies the session at the same time. You could of course open your session, copy the array and close the session inmediately at the top of each script that does not need to modify it.

Comment: You could wait with the call of the next ajax until the current ajax-request ist done. And in the Ajax you can close your session and save it with `session_write_close()` (in PHP)

Comment: @jeroen I'm referring to the laravel session. I'm not sure if it's possible to close the laravel session before the request terminates. Updated to clarify.

Comment: @OliverBähler Waiting for the one that writes to go first and then sending off the other ones (or the other way around) is a way to solve this. It's not an ideal way to solve this because I'll be delaying operations which are not really related to each other. `session_write_close` doesn't apply to me because I'm using the Laravel session which basically is read from redis when the request starts and then written back before the request terminates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it helps anyone this is what I ended up doing:

In my `RouteServiceProvider.php` `boot()` method:

```
Route::group([
    'middleware' => 'readonly',
    'namespace' => $this->namespace,
], function ($router) {
    Route::get("user/{post}","UserController@getPost");
});
```

In my `Kernel.php`:

```
'readonly' => [            
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\StartReadOnlySession::class,            
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,   
        'bindings',
 ]
```

This was basically copied from the `web` route group with the exception of `StartSession` swapped for `StartReadOnlySession`

Here's my `StartReadOnlySession` code (the punchline of the issue):

```
use Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession;
class StartReadOnlySession extends StartSession {
    public function terminate($request, $response) { /* Does nothing */ }
}
```

This this starts the session but does not save it when the request terminates. Everything else behaves identically.

**UPDATE:**

As @woens noted the `terminate` function is no longer used and `saveSession` is used instead so the new code for Laravel 5.8+ users would be:

```php
use Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession;
class StartReadOnlySession extends StartSession {
    public function saveSession($request, $response) { /* Does nothing */ }
}
```

Comment: Nice solution if you have race conditions with ajax

Comment: Note that terminate has been replaced by saveSession($request) in laravel 5.8